# java 8 Collector<String, A, R> is not a functional interface, who can tell why?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

The follow code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors::toList);
    }
}
```

IntelliJ tell me:

`Collector<String, A, R>` is not a functional interface

but when I modify the code as follows, everything is ok, I don't know why?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The reason that the first syntax is illegal is that the target type implied by the method signature—`Stream.collect(Collector)`—is a `Collector`. `Collector` has multiple abstract methods, so it isn't a functional interface, and can't have the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation.

Method references like `Class::function` or `object::method` can only be assigned to functional interface types. Since `Collector` is not a functional interface, no method reference can be used to supply the argument to `collect(Collector)`.

Instead, invoke `Collectors.toList()` as a function. The explicit `<String>` type parameter is unnecessary, and your "working" example won't work without parentheses at the end. This will create a `Collector` instance that can be passed to `collect()`.

Answer (score 4):

The `Collector` interface has multiple methods (`combiner()`, `finisher()`, `supplier()`, `accumulator()`) the require an implementation, so it can't be a functional interface, which can have only one method with no default implementation.

I don't see how your question is related to the attached code.

Comment: I think they meant to use `Collectors.toList()`.